# MIXED_DML_OPERATION on Public Group

Tags: apex

I'm trying to delete public groups and I run into the below:

> MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted
>   after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): User,
>   original object:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@future
public static void deleteGroup(String groupId) {

        List<Group> groups = [ SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Id = :groupId ];

        if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
            System.runAs(new User(Id = Userinfo.getUserId())) {
                delete groups;
            }
        } else {
             delete groups;
        }

}
```

Refer: http://www.tgerm.com/2012/04/mixeddmloperation-dml-operation-on.html